# Cocos2d texture quality vs memory size - how to get acceptable results?

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently trying to reduce the memory size of my textures. I use texture packer already, as well as .pvr.cczs with either RGB565 or RGB5551. This, however, often leads to a huge, unacceptable reduction in texture quality.

Specifically, I got a spritesheet for the main character. In size it's roughly 4k*2.5k pixels. This is not really negotiable as we have lots of different animations and we need the character in a size acceptable for retina displays of ipads. So reducing the size of the character sprite would again result in huge reductions of quality when we use him in the scene.

So of course I'm trying to use 16 bit textures as often as possible. Using the above mentioned spritesheet as a 16 bit texture takes about 17 mb of memory. This is already a lot. As it's a spritesheet for a character, the texture needs transparency and therefor I need to use rgb5551 as colour depth. With only 1 bit for the alpha channel, the character just looks plain ugly. In fact, everything that needs alpha looks rather ugly with only 1 bit for the alpha channel.

However, if I'd use RGB8888 instead the spritesheet uses double the memory, around 34mb. Now imagine several characters in a scene and you'll end up with 100mb memory for characters alone. Add general overhead, sound, background, foreground, objects and UI to it and you'll end up with far too much memory. In fact, 100mb is "far too much memory" as far as I'm concerned.

I feel like I'm overlooking something in the whole process. Like something obvious I didn't do or something. RGB4444 is no solution either, it really looks unacceptably bad.

In short: How do I get acceptable texture quality including alpha channel for less than 100mb of memory? "Not at all"? Because that's kinda where it leads as far as I can see.

Comment: dump the texture cache info : [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo], and it will tell you how much memory is taken by your textures. Then you will know if you have a memory problem that is related to textures or something else. You will also know which textures are the memory hogs.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg yes, this is what I did which is why I know how much memory my spritesheet takes which is why I ask how I can reduce it without sacrificing too much quality.

Comment: Well, if your character's textures are 'non negotiable' , i guess you have your own answer. I dont know what is in the spritesheet, so i wont even start venturing avenues for optimizing.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg as I said, it's the spritesheet for the main character. As he uses up till half to two thirds of the screen in heigth these sprites are relatively large, around 450 pixels high each. Now 15 frames per animation, 10 animations... you see what I'm looking at in size. Which is exactely why I'm asking about how to reduce the memory imprint of it. Or rather: is there a way or do I have to change the size of the spritesheet because there's no other way at all.

Comment: You could switch to a skeleton based system like Spine.  This would allow you to reduce your spritesheet to just the individual components that make up your main sprite instead.

Comment: Though I haven't used Spine, I did write my own skeletal animation system before it was released. It cuts down art dramatically!

Comment: Do you dither your sprites when you use 4444?

Comment: Of course, as I said, I use Texturepacker already.

Answer (score 1):

Split your main texture in 'per character/peranimation/per resolution' files. Use .pvr.ccz because they load faster (much faster, i've measured 8x faster on some devices'). If you are using TexturePacker, you should be able to eliminate most if not all artefacts from the 'pvr' conversion.

When running your scenes, preload only the 'next' posture/stance/combat that you know will need. Experiment with asynchronous loading, with completion block, to signal when the texture is available for use. Dump your unused texture as fast as you can. This will tend to keep the memory requirement flatish at a much lower clip than if you load all animations at once.

Finally, do you really need 15 frames for all these animations ? I get away with as few as  5 frames for some of the animations (idle, asleep, others too). TexturePacker takes of symetrical animations around a certain frame, just points frames midPoint +1 ... midPoint + N to MidPoint -N ... MidPoint -1.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I'm using pvr.ccz already. The 15 frames were an example for the walking animation - that's 15 frames each direction or at least those I cannot reuse with mirroring. I'll check about the asynchronous loading. Lastly, I'll leave this open for a while - maybe I get more useful hints.

Comment: I have the same issue in my current game (16 character classes, 8 directions of travel) .... i can assure you it is possible to 'just in time' load textures, you probably know ahead of time the trajectory (thus the next texture you will need ). Also, i may have a few soldiers with the same images on screen, so i tend to use a batchNode for the idle animation ... just to get the one draw call benefit.

Comment: If i understand, you have actually closer to 30 frames for a walk ? that is a LOT of frames no ???

Comment: 15 frames per direction (up / down / right / diagonal right back / diagonal right front). I'm mirroring to the left. So yeah, that is a lot of frames. Which is where my original problem stems from ;)

Comment: what gets me is 30 frams per direction. At 60 fps that would be .5 seconds and 30 frames per stride (assuming they all display) ... that is a lot. But then again, only you can tell by evaluating how it looks on devices